# League Table so final match day is irrelevant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

With the final matchday of the Premier League coming up I’m just wondering if it was possible to show if there is a set of results from the previous 37 match days that would cause the final match to have no effect on the table.

That is, with 20 teams each playing each other twice throughout the season, is there a way of having the table so that there are at least 4 points between each team after 37 matches?

Very interested in seeing the answers!

Comment: Well not by that reasoning.. if the bottom team were to have 0 points and then 4 points between each team it would leave first with 76 which is well within what is permissible (Max after 37 matches would be 111)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that : I now think it is possible.

Comment: @NoName it is more complicated than that if an unplayed game is between the bottom two teams

Comment: @Henry You're right, thanks. How did you generate your answer?

Comment: Just playing with numbers until they added up to the right numbers and looked flexible enough

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible table with $280$ matches won and lost and $90$ matches drawn.

It should be easy enough to arrange matches which satisfy this table (remembering each team has one it has not played)

```
 W   D   L  Points
26  11   0  89
25  10   2  85
24   9   4  81
23   8   6  77
22   7   8  73
21   6  10  69
20   5  12  65
19   4  14  61
18   3  16  57
17   2  18  53
16   1  20  49
14   3  20  45
12   5  20  41
10   7  20  37
 8   9  20  33
 5  14  18  29
 0  25  12  25
 0  21  16  21
 0  17  20  17
 0  13  24  13
```